# MOTOR POWER Efficiency

Tags: motor, induction-motor

[image]I want to know that when in HVAC we design the units there is always power input is greater than motor size. I want to know that why input power is much greater than motor size.

MOTOR DATA
Input Power         6.5 KW
Motor Power         5.5 KW
Running Current     11.1 A

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the data sheet for the motor and the specs for the HVAC so we know what you are quoting...

Comment: Motors are never 100% efficient.

Comment: What does 'size' mean? I've never seen a size measured in watts! Perhaps output power? 50% efficiency sounds plausible.

Comment: size means output power

Comment: You've had enough time to supply data sheets. VTC as unclear.

Comment: If the input power is calculated by multiplying the input current by the input AC voltage, you are not taking power factor into account. However since you have posted few details, I will vote to close.

Comment: I have added the details and highlighted the required point. Now can anyone help to understand the reason of this difference.

Comment: "MOTOR DATA Input Power 151 W Motor Size 80 W Running Current .71 A" - where is this in the data sheet?

Comment: I am facing same issue on all selections. I have uploaded the same for other unit.

Answer (score 1):

The "Motor power" in kW is MECHANICAL kW, defined as an amount of shaft torque at a given speed, representative of the "kinetic energy" in the system.

The "Motor power input" is the ELECTRICAL power that is consumed by the motor in order to create that mechanical torque and speed (also called "absorbed power"). As mentioned, the motor has losses associated with converting the electrical energy into kinetic energy; magnetic losses in the steel cores that make up the electromagnets, thermal losses in the conductors used inside due to resistance and impedance, friction losses (also thermal) in the bearings and wind resistance in the fans used to dissipate the thermal losses.

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency of a motor is output power / input power. The output power is torque * speed. If you use Newton meters for torque, and rad/sec for speed, the result will be in Watts.

The input power is Volts * Amps * PF. PF is power factor. Power factor accounts for the fact that voltage and current are not perfectly in-phase. Now that the question includes motor data, you can see that the efficiency is 5500 W / 6516 W = 84%.

Motor efficiency varies depending on motor speed and torque. So depending on the exact conditions, you may see a different efficiency than 84%.

Larger induction motors tend to have higher efficiency than smaller ones. 84% seams reasonable for a 5.5kW motor.